# Angularjs typehead directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I am trying to create an reusable typehead directive in AngularJS but I've hit a few bumps on the road. Here is my working example:

Directives.js

```
app.directive('autosuggest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      /* Nothing here yet */
    }
  };
});

app.directive('suggestinput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      // Bind keys
      elem.bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 13) { scope.$emit('listNavigate', { code: e.keyCode }); }
        else {
          // Get suggestions
          scope.getSuggest(attrs.source, elem.val());
        }
      });

      // Listen for suggestion list
      scope.$on('listSelect', function (e, data) {
        elem.val(data.name);
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive('suggestlist', function() {
  var selectedIndex = -1;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$on('listNavigate', function (e, data) {
        if (data.code === 38) {
          selectedIndex--;
          // User pressed up arrow
          elem.children().removeClass('sel');
          elem.children().eq(selectedIndex).addClass('sel');
        } else if(data.code == 40) {
          selectedIndex++;
          // User pressed down arrow
          elem.children().removeClass('sel');
          elem.children().eq(selectedIndex).addClass('sel');
        } else if(data.code == 13) {
          // Prepare data
          var selectData = {};
          selectData.suggestValue = elem.children().eq(selectedIndex).children().html();
          selectData.suggestId = elem.children().eq(selectedIndex).children().attr('item-id');

          // Send data to input(s)
          scope.$emit('listSelect', selectData);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Html:

```
<fieldset autosuggest>
  <input type="hidden" name="languageId">
  <input type="text" suggestinput source="languages">
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save">
  <ul suggestlist ng-show="suggest.languages" class="suggestList">
    <li ng-repeat="language in suggest.languages">
      <a href="#" ng-bind="language.name" item-id="{{language.id}}"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I pass the item-id from the suggestion list to the hidden input?
2. How to make it a reusable component? (make it work even if I have multiple typeheads on the same page)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look @ Angular ui's directive for twitter bootstrap typehead. This'll save you a lot of hassle [ui.bootstrap.typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" id="app">
    <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
        <pre>Model: {{selected| json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS/Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/tZhYR/)**

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3 rc1. I've been waiting for a while for an updated library but haven't found anything yet. Can it be easily modified to work with the latest version of bootstrap? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out, thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even see your first comment, been busy. Did you get the angular.ui.bootstrap to work with the bootstrap 3 rc1? @AngelinSirbu

Comment: Oh, that's great. I'm gonna use B3 in my next project.